# Speed of sound and density

Tags: acoustics, density, speed

The speed of sound in a medium is inversely proportional to the density of the medium. Why?

Comment: can you post the formula for the speed-of-sound?

Comment: "sound speed"$^2$$\sim $"pressure"/"density" but this (very) rough scaling is not true in all materials. Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/555687/226902 . Interesting and related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/502429/226902

Comment: *The speed of sound in a medium is inversely proportional to the density of the medium.* Why do you think that?